# Data lost in terms of data transmission

Tags: host, lost

I have a newbie question.

We learned that data can be lost in many ways during data transmission between hosts, we also learned several methods of error detection and correction.

My question is, what does exactly lost mean in wide web? I mean, where does it go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are "lost" in the sense that packets become corrupted and *dropped* (ie: blocked/erased) by the forwarding router/firewall. Imagine a "black hole" which consume all corrupted/invalid packets.